# ASP.NET - Displaying a Row/Grid of ImageButtons

Tags: c#, asp.net, grid, markup, imagebutton

I'm working on my first asp.net/web development application. Obviously, I'm very new to asp.net development, but I've been doing C# for quite some time and so can rationalize out the logic of the project pretty easily.  However, I'm struggling with some markup issues I'm working on. Here's my situation:

I have a `List` of `Book` objects and each object has a `Title` and `CoverImage` property. Okay. I want to display each book as an `ImageButton` with a border that'll change colors to 'highlight' the one a user clicked.  Actually, this doesn't **have** to be done with an `ImageButton`, but that's what I've been attempting to use up to this point. Users can only have one book selected at a time. Now, I think I can handle the logic of 'radio-buttoning' the books, however, I'm struggling to figure out how to properly display these 'buttons'. Finally, there will be a normal button below the grid of books that will allow users to submit their selection and I need to make sure I can determine exactly which book is selected (perhaps by getting the `Title` of the `Book` object selected?).  This is another area where I've been having trouble as I've attempted to do this with a GridView.

Using a GridView control, I've found that by binding a `List` to the GridView, I can only do a *row* for each Book rather than a "column" for each. At least, using the only methods I know at this time. Also, I need the UI to be 'smart' enough to dynamically change the number of Books displayed in a row based on the image/browser width.

Please, any advice or tips on how I might achieve this type of interface would be much appreciated. 
Even better would be some examples or links with examples as I definitely learn best when I can see example code and rationalize my way through it. Below I put a [colored] wire-frame type of image of what I'm attempting to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Use a Repeater with  CSS to flow horizontally or - simpler - a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bb398790.aspx) with appropriate grouping. http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/010208-1.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an ASP.Net [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bb398790.aspx) control. It should allow you the layout you request with multiple Books per row.

Comment: Nice! I was getting ready to ask you how to make the DataList control 'wrap' my row of Books, but the ListView is working PERFECTLY! Thanks! My one question is: since each book is actually an ImageButton, will I be able to look at the click event handler and get the Book object from, presumably, the 'sender'? Also, how can I add the padding (which I need to change the color of when a book is 'selected') around each book? Should I put the ImageButton in another control and then have THAT control repeat? Something like a 'pane'?